# Не могу понять что не нравится clang`у

Tags: c++, clang

Visual studio 19.00.23506 и g++ 5.4.0 нормально компилируют код приведенный ниже, но вот clang 3.8.0 дает ошибку. Не пойму, что ему не нравится и как надо переписать код, чтобы "этот" его понял.

Код:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const boost::optional<T>& value)
{
    if (value) {
        stream << *value;
    } else {
        stream << "none";
    }
    return stream;
}

namespace XXX 
{
struct A
{
    int x = 1;
};

struct B
{
    A a;
};
} // XXX


std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::A& a)
{
    stream << "x=" << a.x;
    return stream;
}

std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::B& b)
{
    stream << "a=("<< b.a <<")";
    return stream;
}


int main()
{
    boost::optional<XXX::B> b;
    std::wcout << b;    
}
```

Код в online компиляторе [тут](http://rextester.com/live/VNB79185).

Лог компилятора:

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp:10:10: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
                stream << *value;
                       ^
source_file.cpp:47:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<XXX::B>' requested here
    std::wcout << b;    
               ^
source_file.cpp:37:16: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace 'XXX'
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::B& b)
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call`: operator << должен быть объявлен до вызова

Comment: Да перевести я и сам могу, вот только как это исправить не понятно. VC и GCC не против такого.

Comment: Здесь скорее бОльшим вопросом является, почему GCC это принимает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас `operator <<` вызывается из шаблона функции

```
template<class T>
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const boost::optional<T>& value)
```

в контексте, который является *зависимым*, т.е. зависит от шаблонного параметра `T`.

Такие вызовы разрешаются через две фазы поиска имен:

1. Обычный поиск имен, который делается из контекста *определения* вашего шаблонна функции.

   В вашем примере оттуда не находится ничего подходящего, ибо над определением шаблона у вас ничего подходящего не объявлено.
2. ADL поиск (argument-dependent lookup), который делается из контекста *вызова* вашей шаблонной функции (в `main`). Из этого места могут быть видны дополнительные объявления, но при этом эти дополнительные объявления ищутся только в *ассоциированных* пространствах имен (ассоциированных с аргументами вашего вызова).

   В вашем примере ассоциированными пространствами имен являются `std` и `XXX`. В них в контексте вызова ничего нового и подходящего не видно. Глобальное пространство имен в вашем случае ассоциированным не является, поэтому то, что вы там дополнительно наобъявляли, найдено через ADL не будет.

Ваши глобальные операторы

```
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::A& a);
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::B& b);
```

не находятся, код не компилируется.

Либо объявляйте ваши дополнительные операторы *выше* объявления шаблона функции, чтобы они находились на шаге 1. Либо делайте их членами `XXX`, чтобы они находились на шаге 2 (при этом их можно оставить "внизу").

Второй вариант логичнее. С чего это вы вообще решили захламить глобальное пространство имени этими функциями, которые к нему не имеют никакого отношения?

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const boost::optional<T>& value)
{
    if (value) {
        stream << *value;
    } else {
        stream << "none";
    }
    return stream;
}

namespace XXX 
{
    struct A
    {
        int x = 1;
    };

    struct B
    {
        A a;
    };

    std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const A& a)
    {
        stream << "x=" << a.x;
        return stream;
    }

    std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const B& b)
    {
        stream << "a=("<< b.a <<")";
        return stream;
    }
} // XXX

int main()
{
    boost::optional<XXX::B> b;
    std::wcout << b;    
}
```

---

Не закрытым остается только вопрос о том, почему GCC вдруг соглашался компилировать вашу оригинальную версию кода. Я минимизировал пример и задал соответствующий вопрос на EnSO

[GCC and ADL for operators in expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542261/gcc-and-adl-for-operators-in-expressions)

Оказывается, это известный баг GCC ([bug 51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577), а также родственный [bug 70099](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70099)), который проявляется именно при вызове перегруженных операторов через обычный операторный синтаксис. То есть Clang здесь совершенно прав, отвергая вашу версию кода.

VC же вообще не реализует какого-то вменяемого "двухфазного" поиска имен, а просто без разбора видит все подряд, что видно из точки вызова в `main`.

Comment: Значит надо переносить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace XXX 
{
struct A
{
    int x = 1;
};

struct B
{
    A a;
};
} // XXX


std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::A& a)
{
    stream << "x=" << a.x;
    return stream;
}

std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const XXX::B& b)
{
    stream << "a=("<< b.a <<")";
    return stream;
}

template<class T>
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& stream, const boost::optional<T>& value)
{
    if (value) {
        stream << *value;
    } else {
        stream << "none";
    }
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    boost::optional<XXX::B> b;
    std::wcout << b;    
}
```

За подробностями лучше сходить сюда: https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html
Там прямо примеры со всеми ошибками.

Comment: К сожалению не могу переставить. Шаблонный operator<< идет из .h файла, который может быть подключен раньше объявления локального operator<< для A и B типов и нужен, чтоб не писать для каждого типа вариант с boost::optional, boost::shared_ptr и т.д.

Comment: Можно сделать еще 1 h-файл с A и B и operator<< и подключать до .h с operator<<.